# How do I use RxSwift with AlamoFire and SwiftyJSON?

Tags: swift, alamofire, rx-swift, swifty-json

I'm trying to learn `RxSwift` and currently I'm trying to use it in relation to `AlamoFire` and `SwiftyJSON`, that is, to observe when `JSON` has been downloaded so that I can `parse` it. I have working code for getting `JSON`:

```swift
guard let myURL = URL(string: "https://api.myjson.com/bins/e5gjk") else { return }

var myArray = [People]()
let myObserver = Observable.from(myArray)

Alamofire.request(myURL, method: .get)
    .validate()
    .responseJSON{ response in
        guard response.result.isSuccess else {
            print("Error")
            return
        }

        let json = JSON(response.result.value)

        for i in 0...json["employees"].count {
            let people = People()
            people.name = json["employees"][i]["firstName"].stringValue
            people.job = json["employees"][i]["job"].stringValue

            myArray.append(people)
        }

        for i in myArray {
            print(i.name)
            print(i.job)
        }
}

myObserver.subscribe(onNext: {
    print($0)
}, onError: { error in
    print(error)
}, onCompleted: {
    print("completed")
}, onDisposed: {
    print("disposed")
}).disposed(by: DisposeBag())
```

As you can see, I have parsed the `JSON` as well. I guess that the point of `RX` here would be to use the data in `onNext` once it has been parsed, correct? Or have I misunderstood its purpose?

Anyway, I have an observer on `myArray`: `let myObserver = Observable.from(myArray)`. In my head, `subscribe` `onNext` should be triggered as soon as myArray gets data, but that's not happening. What happens is that `completed` is run immediately, then the `JSON` networking and parsing takes place. The subscription is not triggered when `myArray` gets new data. Have I missed something or misunderstood `RX`'s purpose?

***EDIT***
Or wait, should the whole `JSON` handling and parsing be in the `onNext`?

Answer (score 1):

you need to create your observer. This should work :

```
        let observer = Observable<People>.create { (observer) -> Disposable in
            Alamofire.request(myURL, method: .get)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                    print("Error")
                    observer.on(.error(response.result.error!))
                    return
                }
                let json = JSON(response.result.value)

                for i in 0...json["employees"].count {
                    let people = People()
                    people.name = json["employees"][i]["firstName"].stringValue
                    people.job = json["employees"][i]["job"].stringValue

                    observer.on(.next(people))
                    myArray.append(people)
                }

                observer.on(.completed)

                for i in myArray {
                    print(i.name)
                    print(i.job)
                }
           }
           return Disposables.create()
        }
```

then you can subscribe to your observer of type `Observable<People>`

```
    observer.subscribe { (event) in
        switch event {
        case .next(let people):
            print(people.job)
            print(people.name)
        case .error(let error):
            print("error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        case .completed:
            print("completed")
        }
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```